# How to create a variadic (with variable length argument list) function wrapper in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, wrapper, javascript-framework, variable-length

The intention is to build a wrapper to provide a consistent method of calling native functions with variable arity on various script hosts - so that the script could be executed in a browser as well as in the Windows Script Host or other script engines.
I am aware of 3 methods of which each one has its own drawbacks.

1. `eval()` method:

   ```
   function wrapper () {
       var str = '';
       for (var i=0; i<arguments.lenght; i++)
           str += (str ?', ':'') + ',arguments['+i+']';
       return eval('[native_function] ('+str+')');
       }
   ```
2. `switch()` method:

   ```
   function wrapper () {
       switch (arguments.lenght) {
           case 0:
               return [native_function] (arguments[0]);
               break;
           case 1:
               return [native_function] (arguments[0], arguments[1]);
               break;
           ...
           case n:
               return [native_function] (arguments[0], arguments[1], ... arguments[n]);
           }
       }
   ```
3. `apply()` method:

   ```
   function wrapper () {
       return [native_function].apply([native_function_namespace], arguments);
       }
   ```

What's wrong with them you ask?

1. Well, shall we delve into all the reasons why `eval()` is evil? And also all the string concatenation... Not a solution to be labeled "elegant".
2. One can never know the maximum `n` and thus how many `cases` to prepare. This also would strech the script to immense proportions and sin against the holy *DRY* principle.
3. The script could get executed on older (pre- JavaScript 1.3 / ECMA-262-3) engines that don't support the `apply()` method.

Now the question part: is there any another solution out there?

Comment: What Javascript engine in use today doen't support `.apply()`?

Comment: Which native functions do you mean? I can't think of any that have varying arguments depending on the environment

Comment: No platform with such an outdated Javascript implementation is going to be of sufficient interest for you to worry about. Chances are that on such platforms this issue would be the least of your worries.

Comment: Small businesses often can't afford modern hardware and software - there are still tens of thousands - if not more - running win9x systems with ancient browsers and using long unsupported prepackaged Windows Script Host versions

Comment: @meouw - you have `window.alert()` in most browsers, but there is no `window.alert()` in Windows Script Host - `WScript.echo()` method is to be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `apply()`.  And for your *antiquated* execution engines, just do this

```
if ( 'undefined' == typeof Function.prototype.apply )
{
  Function.prototype.apply = function( context, args )
  {
    // whatever hacky way you want to implement it - i guess eval.
  }
}
```

Comment: So, no fourth method? Well then, I'll go with this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just like the automatic 'this' variable, there is an 'arguments' variable that holds all the arguments passed in to the function.  See [javascript variadic](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-variadic-functions).

Comment: The question is about creating a variadic **wrapper** function, one that passes all of its arguments to another function. *Hint: try reading the whole question first next time.* Also, you can not overwrite the `arguments` object of another function externally.