# Helping me in writing a simple function, passing a parametrer value 0 when not declared

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I don't know what is the best way to write it and how to... I have a function like

```
function myFunc(myVal1, myVal2){/*... various things ...*/};
```

where myVal1 and myVal2 are numbers

Sometimes I want to be able to recall the function passing only one parameter just by calling myFunc(myVal1). Doing so I want that myVal2 would have a standard value, if not declared, of 0.

I was thinking to write something

```
function myFunc(myVal1, myVal2){
    if(myVal2 == NaN)
         myVal2 = 0;
    }
}
```

But I don't believe that it is the right way to do it.
Thx very much for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472702/how-to-create-a-variadic-with-variable-length-argument-list-function-wrapper-in might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments that are not set have type undefined, test for it like this.

```
function myFunc(myVal1, myVal2){ 
    if(typeof myVal2 == "undefined") 
         myVal2 = 0; 
    //the rest of the function goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunc(myVal1, myVal2){ 
    // if myVal2 is defined, keep the value, otherwise assign 0
    myVal2 = myVal2 || 0; 
}
```

should do the trick.

more ways to Rome (besides `typeof myVal2 == "undefined"`):

```
function myFunc(myVal1, myVal2){ 
    // if myVal2 is defined, keep the value, otherwise assign 0
    // using a ternary operator
    var myVal2check = myVal2 ? myVal2 :  0; 
}


function myFunc(myVal1, myVal2){ 
    // if myVal2 is defined, keep the value, otherwise assign 0
    // if myVal2 needs to be an integer
    myVal2 = parseInt(myVal2,10) ||  0; 
}

function myFunc(myVal1, myVal2){ 
    // if myVal2 is defined, keep the value, otherwise assign 0
    // using a regexp to determine the 'undefinedness'
    var myVal2check = String(myVal2).match(/undef/i) ? myVal2 :  0; 
}
```

and finally, especially for [David Mårtensson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479137/david-martensson)

```
function myFunc(myVal1){ 
    // no myVal2 defined in the parameter section
    var myVal2check = window.myVal2 ? myVal2 :  0;
}
```

Comment: Trying to access an undefined variable will give JS errors in the console and is bad practise as it can drown out more serious errors, always test for undefined instead.

Comment: That's ehr, a strange comment. In this case (and I answered to this question in particular), the variable is defined as a parameter, so checking it this way is harmless and short. Try this in your console: function bollocks(b1){alert(b1||'b1 has no value');}; [enter] bollocks();

Comment: Tested it some more and I stand corrected it does not generate errors when used as single element in a condition.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!myVal2) {
  myVal2 = 0;
}
```

If you want myVal2 to default to anything other than 0, you have to be more explicit, as 0 evaluates to false. So:

```
if (!myVal2===undefined) {
  myVal2 = 3;
}
```

Comment: `!myVal2` will always return boolean - true or false. So your statement inside `if` will be never executed

Comment: I think the first code example was to illustrate just this, the second is the way he suggests you do it.